# "No action selected" says Django-admin when deleting objects

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-1.10

I've created a simple model Product with couple of fields and then went to `admin.py`. I've registered the `Product`, make some fields `list_editable` and created a new action `duplicate`.

```
def duplicate(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    number = int(request.POST['number'])
    product = queryset.first()
    for i in xrange(number):
        product.id = None
        product.save()

class DuplicateActionForm(ActionForm):
    number = forms.IntegerField()

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','name','color','memory','ga_url','gs_url',)
    list_editable = ('color','memory','name','ga_url','gs_url',)
    action_form = DuplicateActionForm
    # actions = [duplicate,]

admin.site.register(Product,ProductAdmin)
```

When `actions` attribute of `ProductAdmin` class is not commented, I can duplicate objects. The problem is that I can't delete them. When I check row and select `delete selected`, it says: `No action selected`.

This is caused by line:

```
action_form = DuplicateActionForm
```

because if `actions = [duplicate,]` is commented, I can't delete objects correctly until I comment `action_form = DuplicateActionForm`

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: how about by putting your function of `duplicate` inside `ProductAdmin` with `def duplicate(self, request, queryset):` also `duplicate.allow_tags = True`? and the `actions = [ 'duplicate', ]`

Comment: @SancaKembang This didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: You can't delete the duplicated products or any of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `required=False` on your custom form field. After that everything would work as expected.

```
class DuplicateActionForm(ActionForm):
    number = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
```